# Return rows if either a SQL "having" clause or a secondary condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to return rows that meet the criteria of either a `HAVING` clause, *or* a secondary condition outside of it. I'm not sure how to work this logic into the same `SELECT` statement. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Let's say I have one table that has information about some products, and a second table that has  information about the sales figures for these products. I want to select all blue-colored products that have *either* sold 500+ units *OR* were first launched in 2020, regardless of the sales numbers.

The former is captured by a `HAVING` clause that sums up some values that represent sales figures. If, however, this clause returns `false`, I want the product to still be included in the returned rows if the product launch year is "2020".

By this logic, I would expect all of the following products to be included in the results, because they meet at least 1 of the conditions:

```
{"name" => "toaster", "total_sales" => 525, "launch_year" => 2010} # meets the "500+ units sold" condition
{"name" => "oven", "total_sales" => 100, "launch_year" => 2020} # meets the "product was launched in 2020" condition
{"name" => "fridge", "total_sales" => 600, "launch_year" => 2020} # meets both conditions
```

but I would *not* expect the following products to be included in the results, because they meet neither of the conditions:

```
{"name" => "couch","total_sales" => 50, "launch_year" => 1990} # does not meet either condition (<500 units sold, and product not launched in 2020)
{"name" => "chair", "total_sales" => 499, "launch_year" => 2019} # does not meet either condition (<500 units sold, and product not launched in 2020)
```

This is the query itself, although it won't execute successfully:

```
SELECT product.name, product.launch_year, (SUM(sales.units_sold)) as total_sales

FROM product_info as product
LEFT JOIN price_data as sales on product.id = sales.id
    
WHERE product.color = 'blue'

GROUP BY product.name, product.launch_year

HAVING (SUM(sales.units_sold)) >= 500 OR product.launch_year = '2020'
```

The `OR` condition at the very end returns an `invalid column name '2020'` error, as it is syntactically incorrect. However, it represents the logic I am trying to achieve. Is it possible to incorporate this kind of conditional situation into the `HAVING` clause? Or must they exist in two separate `SELECT` statements? Or is there a completely different way to go about doing this?

I've checked for other answers on here, but I've only seen instances where a comparison of the same type was made within a `HAVING` clause, as opposed to a comparison between the `HAVING` clause and a completely separate condition.

Comment: Not sure why you would get "invalid column name " but looks like you need to `group by product.name, product.year_first_on_sale` because `product.name` is unique anyway?

Comment: For this specific case, `OR MIN(product.launch_year)=2020` would seem to give you the result you want.

Comment: Your query looks fine and you should not get the error you say you are getting with single quotes on `'2020'`.